# ImportError: cannot import name certs when trying to import FuelSDK

Tags: error, fuel-sdk, github

I've found some mentions of it on github https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2028

Seems to say that the issue is with updating requests, but I've tried 2.2.1 and 2.3.0 without success. Anyone kno what I need to do? I tried uninstalling and installing which installed an older verison of request and instead gave me error "ImportError: No module named urllib3"

```
import FuelSDK
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-87-3e35a84b5366>", line 1, in <module>
    import FuelSDK

  File "C:\Users\kiowa.jackson\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\FuelSDK\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from client import ET_Client

  File "C:\Users\kiowa.jackson\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\FuelSDK\client.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests

  File "C:\Users\kiowa.jackson\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils

  File "C:\Users\kiowa.jackson\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import certs

ImportError: cannot import name certs
```